# Derivation of the AASHTO formula of interior girder moment

Tags: civil-engineering, bridges, aashto

The interior girder moment formula for one lane loaded for the AASHTO LRFD method is:

$$\begin{align}
mg^{SI}_{moment}&=\left(1.75+\frac{S}{3.6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{L}\right)^{0.35}\left(\frac{1}{N_c}\right)^{0.45} \\
&= \left(1.75+\frac{13}{3.6}\right)\left(\frac{1}{100}\right)^{0.35}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{0.45} \\
&= 0.65\ \mathrm{lane/web}
\end{align}
$$

How is this formula derived? I have not been able to find the original research paper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The live load distribution formulas in the AASHTO LRFD Bridge Design Specifications cannot be derived. As I understand it, they are based on calibration to extensive finite element modeling.

[This is probably the NCHRP report you're looking for.](http://www.trb.org/Main/Public/Blurbs/159050.aspx)

Comment: This was also my thought as well. The commentary to the code usually does a fairly decent job of describing these situations. I don't have the code next to me, so I can't point to the specific pages.